# PostgreSQL: `VIEW` returns no rows with `SPLIT_PART()` columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, postgresql-13

#### Problem Description:

Hi everyone, I'm having some troubles querying on a VIEW whose columns are, in part, the result of `SPLIT_PART()` function on og table's column; I created the VIEW as it follows:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ClientsAddressList(Client_ID, FirstName, LastName, ResidenceAddress, City, PostalCode, Province) AS
SELECT Client_ID, 
       FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       SPLIT_PART(Address, '-', 1) AS ResidenceAddress, 
       SPLIT_PART(Address, '-', 2) AS City, 
       SPLIT_PART(Address, '-', 3) AS PostalCode,     
       SPLIT_PART(Address, '-', 4) AS Province
FROM Clients;
```

My intention was to divide the structured attribute (`Clients.Address` defined as a string `VARCHAR(255)`) which contains all the informations releated to client's domicile in several columns to separately query (e.g. `SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM ClientAddressList WHERE City LIKE 'N%';` or `SELECT Client_ID FROM ClientAddressList WHERE PostalCode = '82305';`).

#### What I experience:

The Clients table contains one test row:

| **Client_ID** | **FirstName** | **LastName** | **ResidenceAddress** | **City** | **PostalCode** | **Province** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00451 | Ezio | Auditore | Via dei Banchi 45 - Florence - 50123 - Florence | Florence | 50123 | Florence |

So my `VIEW` has this row:

| **Client_ID** | **FirstName** | **LastName** | **ResidenceAddress** | **City** | **PostalCode** | **Province** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00451 | Ezio | Auditore | Via dei Banchi 45 | Florence | 50123 | Florence |

I've tried:

```sql
SELECT Client_ID, FirstName, LastName
FROM ClientsAddressList
WHERE City = 'Florence'
```

And it returns no result:

| **Client_ID** | **FirstName** | **LastName** | **ResidenceAddress** | **City** | **PostalCode** | **Province** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

But if I query on columns that are not the result of `SPLIT_PART()` it works:

```sql
SELECT Client_ID, FirstName, LastName, City
FROM ClientsAddressList
WHERE Client_ID = '00451'
```

| **Client_ID** | **FirstName** | **LastName** | **City** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00451 | Ezio | Auditore | Florence |

#### What I expect:

I would `WHERE` clause to work and returns values even on `SPLIT_PART()` result columns:

```sql
SELECT Client_ID
FROM ClientAddressList
WHERE PostalCode LIKE = '%123'
```

| **Client_ID** |
| --- |
| 00451 |

Can someone explain me what could be the problem, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: You got spaces around the dashes in the original data. The result isn't `'Florence'` but `' Florence '` for instance. Why don't you just normalize the original table though?

Comment: @stickybit Oh, I see. So if I just would insert the string as `'Via dei Banchi 45-Florence-50123-Florence'` the problem could be solved. But what do you mean by 'normalize the original table'? I'm sorry, I am a newbie with DBMS systems

Comment: By "normalize the original table" I mean you shouldn't store the address as a string with dashes in the first place but make several columns and store the individual parts. Like a column for the city, the post code, etc. Than you don't even need that awkward view.

Comment: Now I got it. You know, I used the view and that split function just to make the professor know I can use it. That's the reason why

Comment: Hmm, I don't know your Prof, but maybe showing them you know the first normal form (research that term if you don't know it) impresses them more...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sticky bit wrote: there are spaces around the values. There are two ways to deal with this. One way is to just slap a trim() around the expressions in the view:

```
trim(SPLIT_PART(Address, '-', 2)) AS City,
```

The other option is to use an appropriate regex to split the information to remove the whitespace during splitting:

```
select client_id, 
       firstname, 
       lastname,
       address[1] as residenceaddress,
       address[2] as city,
       address[3] as postalcode,
       address[4] as province
from (
  select client_id, firstname, lastname,
         regexp_split_to_array(residenceaddress, '\s*-\s*') as address      
  from clients
) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b92cafc5aa197f52efa9183636f317e0)

---

In the long run you should fix your data model by properly normalizing it and storing those values in separate columns. I don't know how many city names contain dashes in Italy, but in Germany, this pattern would break quickly with city names like "Garmisch-Partenkirchen" or "Leinfelden-Echterdingen"

Comment: I see, thank you. I just wonder what the `trim()` function does

Comment: `trim()` removes spaces at the beginning and the end of a string

Comment: Wonderful. I didn't know that. Thank you so much, it's the second time you answer me, I'm so glad

Comment: @stuckwithmrblonde: Check the manual, you can find the description of all functions, like TRIM(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html